# run specific IP addresses or host names through OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a PC connected to my OpenVPN server, while I'm streaming video games, the stream is interrupted, like its disconnect and reconnect again within no specific time range, sometimes it lasts for 10 minutes and some times 35 seconds, I don't know why even though:

- I'm using my local VPN server (low latency).
- I have a good internet connection with high speed.
- I'm running OpenVPN over UDP
- I'm not facing any lag while watching on e.g. youtube.

The first approach came up to my mind is running just the game through the VPN and keep everything else through my internet gateway.

#### Question:

How do I tell the openVPN to route e.g. only (IP.IP.IP.IP OR Hostname) through the VPN 
and ignore all the other connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a "route IP.add.re.ss/netmask" line (eg route 100.1.1.1/24)for each IP address or range to your OpenVPN configuration file on the client side or "push route IP.adf.re.ss/netmask" on the server config.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is the /24, IP range? can I just put the IP address without it?

Comment: The /24 is an IP range (/24 being a class C). I'm not sure if you can put in just an ip, but putting IP.add.re.ss/32 would achieve the same thing - a /32 is a single IP.